# Overloading the multiplication operator as a member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How would I go about overloading the multiplication operator as a member function in a way that I can multiply both ways?  For example, I know how to overload the multiplication operator as a member class so that this works:

```
MyClass a = a * 2;
```

However, I would also like a member function that allowed for this:

```
MyClass a = 2 * a;
```

How would I overload the multiplication operator to allow this?

Comment: Just overload it is a free function - two free functions actually.

Answer (score 0):

Just overload the operator * like this:

```
MyClass &operator* (int);
```

Also, use templates so you can multiply int, float,double or whatever

Comment: Those declarations are not valid. A member `operator *` can only take one parameter.

Comment: Just tested it, you're right, i'll edit

Comment: But now you don't handle `2 * a`.